# UITableViewCell outlets

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When do outlets get bound to a UITableViewCell instance?  If I print myLabel in the debugger, it's nil and prints:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   @IBOutlet var myLabel: UILabel!

 override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
  super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
 }

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)

   print("\(myLabel)")
 }
}
```

Comment: Try `@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!`

Comment: `awakeFromNib` will be called once they are connected

Comment: My understanding is that @IBOutlet is implicitly weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlets are not yet set when the init method of your tableview cell is called!

I'm not sure what your intention is:

1. If you want to make sure you are not unwrapping a nil optional value just use `if let` like this:

   ```
   if let label = myLabel {
      print("\(label)")
   }
   ```
2. If you want to setup the cell of your tableView, you should first register the cell by calling `tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuse")`. Then dequeue the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` using `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuse")` and make sure you set the values of your cell in `awakeFromNib`:

   ```
   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()

      //you can be sure that myLabel is initialzed here
      print("\(myLabel)") 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting an outlet from the Main Storyboard, your problem could arise if the outlet was accidentally deleted. Recreate the outlet and the label will not be nil anymore.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you are running into a case where myLabel is nil.  It could be while the table view cell is being recycled.

Comment: Subviews are not destroyed during reuse unless done so explicitly in -prepareForReuse. The point of recycling is to remove that overhead in the first place. All elements added from interface builder will be instantiated by the time -awakeFromNib is called and will continue to be available until they are explicitly removed or the cell is deallocated. -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will either initialize a new cell or return an existing cell with all it's subviews from storyboard intact.